# How to redirect path with parameters using htaccess

Tags: .htaccess

I have a series of urls that look like this:

```
example.com/something/page
example.com/another
```

that I need to redirect to

```
example.com/folder/to/file?q=something/page
example.com/folder/to/file?q=another
```

I'm not so sure where to put the **%{QUERY_STRING}** (or if it's needed)? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Its safer to use example.com for examples.  That way, you don't accidentally hit a real domain.  I have changed it.  And I think you will have better luck at Webmasters  https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Well, if you are not sure then take a look at one of the many, many existing answers to that question here on SO. That should get you started.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After breaking the server numerous times, I have finally fixed this myself. I'm not sure if this is the best answer, but just a reference for anyone who might need it:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/([_0-9a-z-]+)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ folder/to/file?q=$1 [L]
```

Comment: You don't need the additional _condition_ (`RewriteCond` directive)... put the regex in the `RewriteRule` _pattern_ intsead. eg. Your 2 directives are the same as `RewriteRule ^([\w-]+)$ folder/to/file?q=$1 [L]`. The `\w` shorthand character class is the same as `[_0-9a-zA-Z]` so also negates the need for the `NC` flag. However, this is not a "redirect" as you've stated in the question, but an internal "rewrite". (A "redirect" generally implies an external HTTP redirect, which would be odd to implement here.)

Comment: However, this does not rewrite URLs of the form `/something/page` (your first example)?

Comment: oh yes you are right! I will have to add one more rule for that: 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/([_0-9a-z-]+)/([_0-9a-z-]+)?$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ folder/to/file?q=%1/%2 [L]

which I bet there must be a better version.

Comment: You shouldn't need to add another rule to handle `/something/page`. The existing rule can be easily adapted to handle both (see my answer). And as mentioned, the preceding `RewriteCond` directive is not required here.

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/([_0-9a-z-]+)$ [NC]
> RewriteRule ^(.*)$ folder/to/file?q=$1 [L]
> ```

Following on from your answer and my earlier comments... there's no need for the preceding `RewriteCond` directive as the necessary regex can be performed in the `RewriteRule` directive itself, which is also more efficient. For example, the above is equivalent to the following:

```
RewriteRule ^([\w-]+)$ folder/to/file?q=$1 [L]
```

The `\w` shorthand character class is the same as `[_0-9a-zA-Z]` which also negates the need for the `NC` (`nocase`) flag.

However, this rule does not handle URLs of the form `/something/page` (with two path segments) as in your first example. You don't need a separate rule for this if you simply want to copy the URL-path in it's entirely to the query string (as in your example).

For example, the following would suffice:

```
RewriteRule ^[\w-]+(/[\w-]+)?$ folder/to/file?q=$0 [L]
```

The above matches both `/another` and `/something/page`.

Note that the `$0` backreference (as opposed to `$1`) contains the entire URL-path that is matched by the `RewriteRule` *pattern*.

Comment: Thanks for this! But I tried both of them and it didn't work, got a "not found" error.

Comment: @phantomhive Hhhmm, but the first rule is _exactly equivalent_ to the rule in your question. So, if your rule worked then that rule must also "work" (for single path segment URLs)?? Presumably `file` is a physical file with extension, like `file.php`?

Comment: yes it is file.php. I'm not sure why too, but I tried the earlier RewriteRule ^([\w-]+)$ folder/to/file?q=$1 [L] too and it simply shows a 404.